# How to return value from sql and display it

Tags: wp-query, sql

In ordinary php I don't have that kind of problem I think but in WP this is a different story. I have query and I want return one value from "liczba_wodo" column.

```
global $wpdb;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $spr_liczbe_wodo = $wpdb->get_row ("select liczba_wodo from wp_ow_adres where adres='Street 12/6'");
        foreach ( $spr_liczbe_wodo as $print )   {
        echo $print->liczba_wodo;
        echo 'Echo test';
        }

    }
}
```

Of course 'echo test' works fine. I think that "$spr_liczbe_wodo" is null or something. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is a PHP issue, the DB query in WordPress is no different, turn on debugging and use `prepare`.

Comment: @Wyck I still have get_row and I see this notice: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`

Comment: This _seems_ ok, what does `var_dump()` on result give you?

Comment: `object(stdClass)#2711 (1) { ["liczba_wodo"]=> string(1) "2" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to return one *value* then use `get_var` instead of `get_row`. `get_var` will return a string. `get_row` will return an array or object.

```
$spr_liczbe_wodo = $wpdb->get_var ("select liczba_wodo from wp_ow_adres where adres='Street 12/6'");
var_dump($spr_liczbe_wodo);
```

The problem with your code, by the way, is that `$spr_liczbe_wodo` is an object, but when you loop over it `$print` is not but you attempt to use it as if it were an object anyway. Through in a couple of `var_dump`s and you can easily see the problem.